# Deprecated Commands in Core 10.1.0?

Tags: stellar-core, upgrade

After upgrading to stellar core 10.1.0, it says that some of the commands have been deprecated. Which are those commands, Could someone please help?

Comment: Make sure to upgrade stellar dependent components,SDk etc.  Some new fields are introduced with horizon as well.

Comment: Having a already synced node(10.0), i tried upgrading to the latest version but faced a issue. I'm not unable to continue from existing downloaded buckets.With a fresh newdb everything works fine, node gets synced. But i need to upgrade with the existing buckets

Answer (score 2):

The new command-line syntax supports the commands listed below. If a command is not in this list, consider it deprecated.

```
alec@alec-MS-7623 ~/product/stellar-core (master) $ src/stellar-core help
usage:
  stellar-core COMMAND

where COMMAND is one of following:
  catchup                           execute catchup from history archives
                                    without connecting to network
  check-quorum                      check quorum intersection from history
  convert-id                        displays ID in all known forms
  dump-xdr                          dump an XDR file, for debugging
  force-scp                         next time stellar-core is run, SCP will
                                    start with the local ledger rather than
                                    waiting to hear from the network
  fuzz                              run a single fuzz input and exit
  gen-fuzz                          generate a random fuzzer input file
  gen-seed                          generate and print a random node seed
  help                              display list of available commands
  http-command                      send a command to local stellar-core
  infer-quorum                      print a quorum set inferred from history
  load-xdr                          load an XDR bucket file, for testing
  new-db                            creates or restores the DB to the genesis
                                    ledger
  new-hist                          initialize history archives
  offline-info                      return information for an offline
                                    instance
  print-xdr                         pretty-print one XDR envelope, then quit
  publish                           execute publish of all items remaining in
                                    publish queue without connecting to
                                    network, may not publish last checkpoint
                                    if last closed ledger is on checkpoint
                                    boundary
  report-last-history-checkpoint    report information about last checkpoint
                                    available in history archives
  run                               run stellar-core node
  sec-to-pub                        print the public key corresponding to a
                                    secret key
  sign-transaction                  add signature to transaction envelope,
                                    then quit
  test                              execute test suite
  version                           print version information
  write-quorum                      print a quorum set graph from history
```